# UITabBarController selected item

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have  `UITabBarController` and push on two views. I want the first view to be the default and the button to be in the "selected" state when it loads.

My problem is the tabBarItem does not have the selected background when it loads. I have to tap on it to show the selected. I'm also using custom images for the tab bar items as well and have them being configured in each view that gets added to the tabBarController.

I'm using this to set the selected item:

```
_tabBarController.selectedViewController = [_tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

The UITabBarItem gets created in each view that I add to the tabBarController:

```
-(UITabBarItem *)tabBarItem
{
    return [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator_map.png"]  tag:0];
}
```

How can I also have the tabBarItem show the selected state?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I am pushing a tabbarcontroller and the initial tab icon is not selected (despite the viewcontroller being shown correctly). Only tapping on the actual tab icon selects it. And I am setting the `selectedIndex` programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code of display selected tabBarItem when your tabBar is loaded.

```
[_tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; // your can set index as per your requirement.
```

**Eited:**

Make sure that you created your tabBarItem such like

```
UITabBarItem* myTestingItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
[myTestingItem  setFinishedSelectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"btnTabItem-SelectedImage.png"]
              withFinishedUnselectedImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"btnTabItem.png"]];
```

Comment: But it doesn't give the tabBarItem the "selected" state. I still have to tap to get it to show that state.

Comment: I Updated the question to show how I'm creating the tabBarItem. Right now I'm not setting a unselectedImage, but when I tap I get one.

Comment: I don't have this image "btnTabItem-SelectedImage.png", iOS is putting the "selected" background around the item automatically when I tap it.